# Can we generate json schema and mvc app using mix ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api?

Tags: json, phoenix-framework, elixir

In the [readme](https://github.com/AgilionApps/ja_serializer) it says we can unless I am missing something because running something like this:

```
mix ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api Market markets name:string phone:string
```

throws back:

```
** (RuntimeError) could not find changeset_view.ex in any of the sources
    lib/mix/phoenix.ex:24: anonymous fn/5 in Mix.Phoenix.copy_from/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1622: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    lib/mix/phoenix.ex:19: Mix.Phoenix.copy_from/5
    lib/mix/tasks/ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api.ex:57: Mix.Tasks.JaSerializer.Gen.PhoenixApi.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Comment: What version of `ja_serializer` are you using? Make sure it's the latest. I ran into this error and had to update and it worked fine.

Comment: @HarrisonLucas give me the version?